# How to update a column with result of calculating a column in another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom, json

Using SharePoint Online, I have 2 lists: A and B.

There are 2 columns in **A**: `EmpCode`, `Sum`

There are 2 column in **B**: `EmpCode`, `Number`

I want to update `Sum` in List A with the sum of `Number` in List B where the same `EmpCode` when creating an item in List B.

How I can do that with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using SharePoint Designer workflow

1. Add a new workflow and attach it to List B
2. Inside the workflow store the current item `EmpCode` & `Number` into two variables
3. Next use Read List Item Action and find the item in List A where `EmpCode` = Varibale EmpCode
4. As part of step 3 read the `Sum` and store it in another variable
5. Now do calculation and add variable sum read from 4 with number
6. Use an Update List Item action to update the value back in List A